# R - Equivalent inputs resulting in different outputs for a sequence

Tags: r

I am running into some behaviour with R that I find confusing. Does anyone have any insight into what is going on here?

Define two objects

```
i <- 5
nr <- 10
```

So i + 2 and nr + 1

```
> i+2
[1] 7

> nr+1
[1] 11
```

So to create a sequence from 7 to 11 I could do this:

```
7:11
```

But my question why does this not produce the same result?

```
i+2:nr+1
```

We already established above that it's input numbers are equivalent. Obviously I'm missing something here but I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Oh I see this makes sense.

Comment: @R-Fever That is a worst title and won't be as likely to get picked up in a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just discovered the prime R gotcha, namely: `1:n-1` produces the sequence `0, 1, 2, ..., n-1`.

To obtain what you desire, wrap the expressions in brackets:

```
1:(n-1)
```

or use

```
seq.int(1, n-1)
```

---

The reason for the issue is [operator precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) - `?`Syntax`

Comment: While the answer is the same, it's more of a result of a code bug. I did look for a canonical answer, but didn't find one,

Comment: To me this question the other question should have been closed and this one kept open since it is much clearer.